# Android Media player does not play sound files over HTTP

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-permissions

I tried to play an mp3 file from URL in Media Player but it not working until I changed the HTTP to https and it works.

I want to know is it possible to play it over HTTP? is there any config or permission I have to set?

**this is my code:**

```
 String url2 = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=17xzsNfCqDqk3hSUtkJ4U4VjHX76knFjx";
 MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

  player.setDataSource(url2);
  player.prepareAsync();
  player.setOnPreparedListener((mp) -> {
            player.start();

            });
```

**and the other info:**

- minSdkVersion 17
- targetSdkVersion 28
- Nokia 6 and android version 9 for test device

Comment: I think link is navigating to some other link/source.
can you try with https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3?

in your case it is https://doc-0c-8c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/koqk0ortrd5os34ln49a5sd3mvkbvuhs/6i18hll7s1hujbkvepja4ll9ltdhrk4o/1583384025000/11500107269081690173/17930272396244300339Z/17xzsNfCqDqk3hSUtkJ4U4VjHX76knFjx?e=download&nonce=7cha2op6inut0&user=17930272396244300339Z&hash=6oadfhgfnomupk6qhtl4n

Comment: ur sound link with https works but without it is not working.

Comment: other link I had provide, is it working?

Comment: No the second link is not working at all http not https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

the problem is because of the No Network Security Config specified and using the platform default.

so I added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to manifest and it works correctly.

```
<application
  ...
  ...
  ...
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```